# With DEBUG=False django in EC2 in AWS, domain, stage.example.com is not reachable

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I have setup a Django server to serve my stage environment like http://stage.example.com.  I entered CNAME for the 'stage' to be like ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute.amazonaws.com in my dns setup.  This worked fine until I flipped DEBUG = False in setting.

With DEBUG=False, stage.example.com is not reachable and ended up with DNS Lookup failure.

BTW, I added stage.example.com in ALLOWED_HOST.
How do I make stage.example.com work under production mode in Django?

Edit: I used gunicorn and nginx on top of Django.

Comment: Are you using the Django development server, Gunicorn etc..?

Comment: Yes. I used gunicorn and nginx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this worked out later time.  The issue was due to PREPEND_WWW django setting.  With this option on, DNS was not resolved because it keeps going to www.stage.xxx.xxx first before it is resolved by DNS.

Comment: The setting is PREPEND_WWW

Answer (score 1):

If nginx / gunicorn generally you can run on 127.0.0.1 since nginx is a  reverse proxy.

```
# settings.py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']
```

Nginx conf in sites-available / sites-enabled

```
server {
    server_name example.com;

    access_log off;

    location /static/ {
        alias /var/www/django-path-to-static-root;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
}
```

gunicorn

```
gunicorn something.wsgi --bind 127.0.0.1:8001
```

Comment: I followed this page http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/ for my setup, which uses socket connection.  But this calls for bind to other port. For that, I have to change many places.  Let me try it out and post the result here.

Comment: This is still an issue with extra top domain like 'stage' or 'prod' but it works ok with actual production domain like 'example.com'.  So, I decided not to change it. But thanks for replying!